# Create Umbraco context with custom routes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, umbraco, umbraco7

With umbraco 7 I have a custom controller which Im using with some custom routes

```
public class BlogController : RenderMvcController
{
    public override ActionResult Index(RenderModel model)
    {

        Int32 nodeID = umbraco.uQuery.GetNodeIdByUrl("/blog");

        var umbracoHelper = new UmbracoHelper(UmbracoContext.Current);
        IPublishedContent content = umbracoHelper.TypedContent(nodeID);

        BlogViewModel vm = new BlogViewModel(content);

        return CurrentTemplate(vm);

    }

}
```

Im getting the blog context manually by ID then though the umbracoHelper which works fine on a normal route but when I go to the custom route UmbracoContext.Current has lots of null values, I assume because it doesn't know where it is?

Is there a way to use UmbracoHelper without UmbracoContext.Current or can I create a dummy context?

Thanks

Comment: Any particular reason not to use an Umbraco controller? That should give you an UmbracoContext automatically. https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/implementation/Controllers/

Comment: Yes I inherit from an umbraco controller BlogController : RenderMvcController

Regardless of controller because my custom route does not relate to the tree I wont have context?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I totally misread your snippet :-/ No idea off the top of my head why UmbracoContext.Current is null for you.

Comment: What you're trying to do is route hijacking through templates. in this case you're not looking for Umbraco Context. You need your own custom model in which you instantiate in the controller. The answer is here:

https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/reference/routing/custom-controllers

If you don't need to route hijack then inherit from SurfaceControllers and you don't need anything as it gives you the umbracoHelper on its own by typing Umbraco.TypedContent(pageId). (Umbraco. in this case is the umbracohelper). Let me know if that helped I'll post it as the answer